# how to vertically split an array and add one column in to each of splitted array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to split below array

```
A = 
[[0.45 + 0j, 1 - 2j, 3 - 4j, 5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 9 - 10j, 11 - 12j, 13 + 14j, 15 + 16j, 17 - 18j, 19 - 20j, 21. - 22j, 23 - 24j],
 [0.45 + 0j, 1 - 2j, 3 - 4j, 5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 9 - 10j, 11 - 12j, 13 + 14j, 15 + 16j, 17 - 18j, 19 - 20j, 21. - 22j, 23 - 24j],
 [0.45 + 0j, 1 - 2j, 3 - 4j, 5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 9 - 10j, 11 - 12j, 13 + 14j, 15 + 16j, 17 - 18j, 19 - 20j, 21. - 22j, 23 - 24j],
 [0.45 + 0j, 1 - 2j, 3 - 4j, 5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 9 - 10j, 11 - 12j, 13 + 14j, 15 + 16j, 17 - 18j, 19 - 20j, 21. - 22j, 23 - 24j],
 [0.45 + 0j, 1 - 2j, 3 - 4j, 5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 9 - 10j, 11 - 12j, 13 + 14j, 15 + 16j, 17 - 18j, 19 - 20j, 21. - 22j, 23 - 24j]]
```

into

```
B = 
[[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  18, 20, 22, 24]]]
```

and then add below array

```
R = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

into it as below

```
C = 
[[[0.1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [0.0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[0.2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [0.0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[0.3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [0.0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[0.4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [0.0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]],
 [[0.5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 , 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
  [0.0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]]]
```

I want to use only numpy library.

I already tried below function and it did not help

index separation
    hsplit
    vsplit
    split
    reshape
    zip

trials like for splitting

```
A = np.vsplit(A,5)
A = np.array(A)
```

or

```
A = np.hsplit(A,5)
A = np.array(A)
```

or

```
A = np.reshape(-1,A,5)
A = np.array(A)
```

or

```
A = np.reshape(A,5,-1)
A = np.array(A)
```

adding part is easier I use complex concept and it works for adding ...

If you have any idea of using other functions?
I need only a clue and I will write the code myself!

Comment: You have jagged arrays, none of your methods will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
              [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 1010]])
R = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Lets start by reshaping and transpoing `A`, so that is matches the structure in the specified expected output:

```
A = A.T.reshape(-1, 2, 2).transpose(0,2,1)

print(A)

[[[   1    2]
  [  11   22]]

 [[   3    4]
  [  33   44]]

 [[   5    6]
  [  55   66]]

 [[   7    8]
  [  77   88]]

 [[   9   10]
  [  99 1010]]]
```

Now we can use `np.column_stack` to stack a new column of `0s` to `R`, and then `np.dstack` to stack it depth-wise to the reshaped `A`:

```
R = np.column_stack([R, np.zeros(len(R))])
C = np.dstack([R,A])
```

---

```
print(C)

array([[[   0.1,    1. ,    2. ],
        [   0. ,   11. ,   22. ]],

       [[   0.2,    3. ,    4. ],
        [   0. ,   33. ,   44. ]],

       [[   0.3,    5. ,    6. ],
        [   0. ,   55. ,   66. ]],

       [[   0.4,    7. ,    8. ],
        [   0. ,   77. ,   88. ]],

       [[   0.5,    9. ,   10. ],
        [   0. ,   99. , 1010. ]]])
```

Comment: But the question was already answered and accepted right? @NoneNone you can't really just modify it, as it seems am I'm answering something else.. For that you should ask a new question

Comment: I am sorry, your answer was completely correct for that special state/case but when I increase the array, I do not know where it goes wrong. Moreover they are similar. I am afraid to open a new question due to similarity.